# Matrix Factorization algorithms for Recommender Systems

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, references, recommender-system

I need to learn about Matrix Factorization for recommender systems, so I downloaded this paper [https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-%5bNetflix%5d.pdf) but I found it too shallow. It didn't explain the concepts in depth for me. So can you please recommend some good papers/resources to learn about the topic?

I need to learn about them so I can implement a matrix factorization model.

Comment: [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html) by Anand Rajaram available for free ONLINE

Answer (score 5):

Matrix factorisation is part of Numerical Linear Algebra (NLA).  The following are some useful books in NLA and Data Mining / Statistical Learning.

- The classic in NLA is Golub & Van Loan's Matrix Computations.  [Van Loan's webpage](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/Books/booksHome.htm) lists his books in and links to others.
- A modern approach that's great for self-study, is [Numerical Linear Algebra](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/text.html) by Trefethen & Bau, partially available online on Trefethen's  website.  Bau was working at Google last I checked.
- For a **data mining focus**, [Numerical Linear Algebra and Applications in Data Mining](http://en.booksee.org/book/509269) by Lars Elden is available online.
- A classic on the statistical side is [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman.  The authors have graciously made available their entire book online.  This requires a fair bit of mathematical background, but the introductions to each topic will be accessible more generally.
- A lighter version of the above is [Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/getbook.html), by the same authors plus Daniella Witten.  This is also available online by the authors and provides useful R code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2043956. For more details you can look into [*Recommender system handbook*](http://www.springer.com/computer/ai/book/978-0-387-85819-7).

I am working on similar problems. For more details or discussion mail me @ pranav.waila[at]gmail[dot]com.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is generally better to have your information (eg, your email address) on [your userpage](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/48846/pranav-waila) rather than in an answer. Can you say a little more about the references you link to, what they contain, etc?